# Как отправить форму на сайте через python requests

Tags: html, python, веб-программирование, requests

Я при изучении программирования я столкнулся с проблемой, мне надо заполнить и отправить форму по типу:

```
<form method=“GET(или POST)”>
Введите логин: <input type=“text” />
Введите пароль: <input type=“password” />
<input type=“submit” value=“submit”>
</form>
```

И я знаю что в requests есть способы авторизации, но я не знаю какой именно надо применять. Если можно прошу в ответе показать подробнее что надо писать в аргументах, а то из документации не сильно понятно.

Comment: Отправлять форму как обычно и обрабатывать получаемые куки как обычно — обе вещи описаны прямо на первой странице документации requests: http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/quickstart/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Пример (взят отсюда)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17633072/5741205):

```
import requests

# Fill in your details here to be posted to the login form.
payload = {
    'inUserName': 'username',
    'inUserPass': 'password'
}

# Use 'with' to ensure the session context is closed after use.
with requests.Session() as s:
    p = s.post(LOGIN_URL, data=payload)
```

Comment: (хм, а вот сессий очень зря нету на первой странице документации requests)

Answer (score 0):

Воть полностью работоспособная "болванка" для получения токена и ID.

Сами доделайте отправную точку к методу `Check`.

Использую `session = requests.Session()` в силу того, что в нём встроены "печеньки" (хотя, в случае ВК незнаю, есть ли они там).

```
#by VectorASD
from urllib.parse import urlencode, parse_qs
import requests
def Bot():
  def Check(response):
    #print("Akk:", login, password)
    if "error" in response:
      Err = response["error"]
      if Err == "need_validation":
        Type = response["validation_type"]
        if Type == "2fa_sms":
          sid, phone, url = response["validation_sid"], response["phone_mask"], response["redirect_uri"]
          print("2fa авторизация!")
          print("Телефон:", phone)
          resp = session.get(url)
          #with open(GPath + "AuthDoc.html", "wb") as file: file.write(resp.content)
          #print("Ответ:", resp.content)
          url = "/".join(url.split("/")[:3]) 
            + resp.content.split(b'<form method="post" action="', 1)[1]
            .split(b'"', 1)[0].decode("utf-8", errors = "replace")
          print("URL:", url)
          values = {
            "code": input("Введите код: "),
            "remember": int(True),
          }
          resp = session.post(url, values)
          Str = resp.content.decode("cp1251", errors = "replace").replace("<b>", "").replace("</b>", "")
          if not Str.count(
            "Пожалуйста, не копируйте данные из адресной строки для сторонних сайтов. 
             Таким образом Вы можете потерять доступ к Вашему аккаунту."):
            print("Странная ответочка:", Str)
          #print(resp.url.split("#", 1))
          Dict = parse_qs(resp.url.split("#", 1)[1])
          #print(Dict)
          success = Dict["success"][0] == "1"
          if success: return Dict["access_token"][0], int(Dict["user_id"][0])
          else: print("Проваль [>;/] :", resp.url.split("#", 1), Dict)
        else: print("    2fa:", response)
      elif Err == "invalid_client": print("    Нельзя войти:", response)
      elif Err == "need_captcha":
        print("    Нарвался на капчу:", response)
        sid, url = response["captcha_sid"], response["captcha_img"]
        print("SID:", sid)
        print("url:", url)
        #Code = Captcher(session.get(url).content)
        Code = input("Ввод кода: ")
        print("Code:", Code)
        return CaptchaLogin(sid, Code)
      else: print("    Не известный тип ошибки:", response)
    elif "access_token" in response:
      print("    Вход удался:", response)
      return response["access_token"], response["user_id"]
    else: print("    Необрабатываемое исключение:", response)
  def CaptchaLogin(sid, Key):
    response = session.get("%s&username=%s&password=%s&captcha_sid=%s&captcha_key=%s" % (
    api_request, login, password, sid, Key)).json()
    return Check(response)
```